# How to convert Infrastructure.DbQuery to ViewModel type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have written the following linq query in .net mvc project:

```
        var list = (from i in db.Inventories
                    join o in db.SalesOrders on i.OrderId equals o.IID
                    join c in db.CustomerSuppliers on i.SLCode equals c.IID
                    join p in db.SalesPersons on o.SalesPerson equals p.IID into ps
                    from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where i.IID == id
                    select new SalesViewModel
                    {
                        IID = i.IID,
                        DocNo = i.DocNo,
                        DocDt = i.DocDt,
                        RefNo = i.RefNo,
                        RefDate = i.RefDate,
                        DocType = type,
                        DocDesc = i.DocDesc,
                        SLCode = i.SLCode,
                        OrderId = o.OrderId,
                        ClientName = c.Name,
                        SalesPerson = p.Name
                    });



        return View(list);
```

I define model inside my view like:

```
@model WebApp.Models.SalesViewModel
```

When I run the project I am getting the following error:

> "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[WebApp.Models.SalesViewModel]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'WebApp.Models.SalesViewModel'."

I am returning the `SalesViewModel` model in my query `select new SalesViewModel`.
Any Clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error clearly says that the object returned from the Controller to the view is not of type `WebApp.Models.SalesViewModel`.

Try get the the `DBQuery` result to `SalesViewModel` by using `FirstOrDefault()`.

```
SalesViewModel list = (from i in db.Inventories
                    join o in db.SalesOrders on i.OrderId equals o.IID
                    join c in db.CustomerSuppliers on i.SLCode equals c.IID
                    join p in db.SalesPersons on o.SalesPerson equals p.IID into ps
                    from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where i.IID == id
                    select new SalesViewModel
                    {
                        IID = i.IID,
                        DocNo = i.DocNo,
                        DocDt = i.DocDt,
                        RefNo = i.RefNo,
                        RefDate = i.RefDate,
                        DocType = type,
                        DocDesc = i.DocDesc,
                        SLCode = i.SLCode,
                        OrderId = o.OrderId,
                        ClientName = c.Name,
                        SalesPerson = p.Name
                    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: "Try cast the DBQuery to List" that's far from what your code does.

Comment: That *executes the query* which is extremely different to casting. Also, what makes you think the OP wants a `List<T>` when it's filtering by ID?